# Dictionary<string, int> to List<Dictionary<string, int>> in c#

Tags: c#

Is there a clean method to do this?

I tried

```
List<Dictionary<string, int>> myList = new List<Dictionary<string, int>>();
myList = myDict.ToList();
```

But that doesn't work, I'm looking for something similar to above if that is possible?

Comment: Well what would you want it to do? Please post a [mcve] rather than just a couple of lines that refer to a variable that you haven't shown... (And why initialize `myList` only to reassign it in the next statement?)

Comment: You want this or `List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>`;

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal Sorry I am new to c#, do I use this like `List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> = myDict.ToList();` ?

Comment: If you really want `List<Dictionary<string, int>>` then just do this : `List<Dictionary<string, int>> meList = new List<Dictionary<string, int>>(); meList.Add(meDictionary);`... But I doubt that you want that.

Comment: Why you want that list, doesn't make much sense, does it? Every single key-value in it's own dictionary. Btw, what means _"it doesn't work"_? Show the error message.

Comment: If you want one combined dictionary : myList.Select(x => x.Select(y => new { key = y.Key, value = y.Value })).SelectMany(x => x).GroupBy(x => x.key).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y);

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What is the context? You have a dictionary of what and want a list of what? How are you going to use the list later on? Some example inputs and expected outputs would help.

Answer (score 0):

There are two statements in your question.

Assuming first is correct then do

```
myList.Add(myDict);
```

But if your second statement is correct then your first statement should be

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> myList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
        Dictionary<string, int> myDict = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        myDict.Add("1", 1);
        myDict.Add("2", 2);
        myDict.Add("3", 3);
        myDict.Add("4", 4);
        myDict.Add("5", 5);

        List<Dictionary<string, int>> myList = new List<Dictionary<string, int>>();

        myList.Add(myDict);
```

Something like this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
Dictionary<int, string> myDict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
myDict.Add(1, "one");
myDict.Add(2, "two");
myDict.Add(3, "three");

List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> myList = myDict.ToList();
```

And retrieve data in this way:

```
// example get key and value
var myKey = myList[0].Key;
var myVal = myList[0].Value;
```